# How do i iterate over API response in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Hello I'm a noobie in Vue, How do I iterate through this in my template and render it ?
I can console log everything but I can't render it on my page.

API URL : `https://private-922d75-recruitmenttechnicaltest.apiary-mock.com/customexercises/`

I've tried this **:**

```
 <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
    <h2>{{ post.exercises.id }}</h2>
    <h2>{{ post.exercises.name }}</h2>
  </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: don't post pictures, post code and data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close! :)

[See this playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, onBeforeMount } from 'vue'
  
const posts = ref([])

onBeforeMount(async () => {
  posts.value = await fetch("https://private-922d75-recruitmenttechnicaltest.apiary-mock.com/customexercises/").then(raw => raw.json()).then(json => json.exercises)
})
</script>

<template>
<div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
    <h2>{{ post.id }}</h2>
    <h2>{{ post.name }}</h2>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the API response, `exercises` is an array of objects. Hence, to access it's object properties you have to iterate over the `exercises` array.

**Demo :**

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      posts: {
        exercises:[{  
          id: "5c10de5792437a5c67e74ba2",
          name: "Pull Up",
        }, {  
          id: "5c0e7f6d41403b024ad987cc",
          name: "Barbell Bicep Curl",
        }]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="post in posts.exercises" :key="post.id">
    <h2>{{ post.id }}</h2>
    <h2>{{ post.name }}</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```